# A popular quote from a math rebus

Tags: mathematics, rebus, quote

Find the very famous quote from this mathematic rebus.

> $ \sqrt{4b^2} / -2b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is

> To be or not to be

be cause

> √4b2/−2b = 2b/ -2b

Which can be read as

> To be or (/) not to be

Comment: oooo... the rebus seams too easy..

Comment: Apart from being too obvious,the rebus also seems to be a bit loose. Division does not mean "or". and minus does not mean "not". If the rebus were "answer² = 4b²" then the answer could be "2b or minus 2b", which is a bit better in my opinion, but still leaves the minus/not mismatch. Also, if the solution is found by simplifying the expression, isn't 2b/(−2b) just −1?